# Issue with Barnsley fern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I've written this code for Barnsley fern in PyCharm but the error "Index error: list index out of range" showed up for new x and y. can anyone help me? the code is :

```
import stddraw
import sys
import random

n = int(sys.argv[1])
cx = []
cy = []
x, y = 0, 0
stddraw.setPenRadius(0)

for i in range(n):
r = random.randrange(1, 100)
if r <= 2:
    x = 0.5
    y *= 0.27 * cy[i]
if 3 <= r <= 17:
    x = 0.17 * cx[i] - 0.21 * cy[i] + 0.41
    y = 0.22 * cx[i] + 0.18 * cy[i] + 0.09
if 18 <= r <= 32:
    x = -0.14 * cx[i] + 0.26 * cy[i] + 0.57
    y = 0.25 * cx[i] + 0.22 * cy[i] - 0.04
if 33 <= r <= 99:
    x = 0.78 * cx[i] + 0.3 * cy[i] + 0.11
    y = -0.3 * cx[i] + 0.74 * cy[i] + 0.27

    stddraw.point(x, y)

stddraw.show()
```

Comment: Observe: `cy` and `cx` are empty lists. On each iteration you attempt to access either `cy[i]` or `cx[i]` _but_ never append anything to these lists. What do you think would `cy[i]` be, for example?

Comment: yes, you right. but there is no difference when i fill these array.

Comment: each of these lists must have at least `n` elements for this to work.